# An uniformly convergent iterated function series

Tags: calculus

**Let $f$ be twice continuously differentiable on $[-1,1]$ with ragne $[-1,1]$, and $$f(0)=0, 0<f'(0)<1/2, |f''(x)|\leq M<1.$$
Denote by 
$$f_1(x)=f(f(x)), f_n(x)=f(f_{n-1}(x)),\ n=1,2,\cdots.$$
Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$ is uniformly convergence on $[-1,1]$.**

Since $$|f_n(x)|=|f(f_{n-1}(x))-f(0|\\
=|f'(\xi)| |f_{n-1}(x)|$$
we need only to bound $|f'(x)|$, but I could not estimate it $\leq$ some $q<1$. In fact, 
$$|f'(x)|=|f'(0)+\int_0^x f''(t)dt|\leq 1/2+Mx.$$
This bound is too large...

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$ notice that, via integrating $f''$ twice:

$$f(x) \leq x/2 + Mx^2/2 = x/2(1+Mx) \leq x/2(1+M).$$

Since $M<1$, $(1+M)/2<1$, so

$$\left | \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) \right | \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left ( \frac{1+M}{2} \right )^n $$

You can write more or less the same thing when $x<0$.